# Should tags [manage.py] and [django-manage.py] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

These seem to me to be exact duplicates...

[Description of [manage.py]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manage.py):

> `manage.py` is a command-line utility for Django's administrative tasks. It is an automatically created thin wrapper around `django-admin.py`.

[Description of [django-manage.py]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-manage.py):

> django-manage.py refers to Django's command-line utility for common administrative tasks.

Do they not mean the same?